# Find name of file being processed by Mapper

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, cloud

I am learning MapReduce. I have following code to find name of the file, whose chunk/block is processed by mapper.

```
FileSplit fs=(FileSplit)context.getInputSplit();
String fileName=fs.getPath().getName();
System.out.println("File: " + fileName + " Path: " + fs.getPath().getName().toString());
```

But it doesn't proceed. Don't know where is error. Please help.

Comment: getName() will give you the filename while just getPath().toString() will give you the complete path. And what do you mean by 'it doesn't proceed' ? where are you searching for the sysout ?

Comment: Look in the logs for the actual map task (via the job tracker web ui), not on command line of the console where you submitted the job from